# How to resuse a pyfftw object?

Tags: python, pyfftw

Perhaps it's just my misunderstanding, but how do you reuse a pyfftw object?

When I run something like the following code, `img1_fft` and `img2_fft` are the same despite receiving different input. When I uncomment the line that reconstructs the `fftwObj`, I get the desired output though.

```
inArray = pyfftw.empty_aligned(optimalSize, dtype='complex64')
inArray[ 0:img1.shape[0] , 0:img1.shape[1] ] = img1;
fftwObj = pyfftw.builders.fft2(inArray)
img1_fft = fftwObj(inArray)

inArray = pyfftw.empty_aligned(optimalSize, dtype='complex64')
inArray[ 0:img2.shape[0] , 0:img2.shape[1] ] = img2;
# fftwObj = pyfftw.builders.fft2(inArray)
img2_fft = fftwObj(inArray)
```

Am I doing something wrong since the whole point of "planning" was to not have to reconstruct pyfftw objects? I would like to just use the same pyfftw object (since all of my images are the same size) and just change the input to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. There is no copy of the output array except explicitly, so `img2_fft is img1_fft` returns `True`.

You can copy the output using `.copy()`, or you can explicitly [set the output array](http://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#pyfftw.FFTW.__call__) from your own array.

Comment: Hmm ok. So in my case, is there any point to using pyfftw? Should I just use numpy's implementation? Because I don't really see how "planning" works in pyfftw otherwise.

Comment: @J-Win what? The planning is about establishing the fastest algorithm for the transform. What is the problem with what is happening here? You're not replanning. Setting the data array is independent of the planning step. The reason the array is not changed by default is for performance reasons - it is up to the user to change the array.

Comment: @J-Win Indeed, in `pyfftw`, you don't need to know anything about the notion of planning (and it's not really mentioned in the docs). An `FFTW` object encapsulates a plan - it is the very notion of what it means to plan using fftw, but it's entirely hidden behind an OO interface.